# mopabootstrap fosuserbundle translation labels

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I cant get the form_widget (from mopabootstrapbundle) to use the translation (from FOSUserBundle) to work in the registration form (from FOSUserBundle) after extending it to my bundle.

https://github.com/phiamo/MopaBootstrapBundle/issues/8

my problem is the same as the above issue, but I cannot understand how it is solved.

---

I guess I must somehow use the translation_domain from FOSUserBundle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the way I dealt with my problem

https://github.com/phiamo/MopaBootstrapBundle/issues/8

Answer (score 0):

did you make all the steps as on this post: https://github.com/phiamo/MopaBootstrapBundle/issues/8#issuecomment-2842368 and especially lines:

> copied the whole templates dir from views/Registration to
>   app/FosUserBundle/views/Registration/